# Android Drawing text with opengl es crashes after a few minutes

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, canvas, frame-rate

I've created an opengl surface and everything works fine, however when I try to draw text onto it using the following method:

```
public void loadFPSTexture(GL10 gl){

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.BLACK);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setTextSize(35);
    textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    canvas.drawText("FPS "+reportedFramerate, 10,35, textPaint);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, texturesFPS, 0);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesFPS[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Then used in my onDraw function with:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesFPS[0]);
gl.glTranslatef(-surfaceSize.x/1.5f, surfaceSize.y/1.5f, 0.0f);
gl.glScalef(10, 10, 1.0f);
gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, saturation_head); 
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0,vertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureFPSBuffer);
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

I get a weird crash and the surface is unable to be drawn after this point. Logcat shows a constant stream of the following:

```
E/Adreno200-EGL( 2578): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=32 offs=1536000
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2578): GL error 0x0505
E/Adreno200-EGL( 2578): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=32 offs=1536000
E/Adreno200-EGL( 2578): egliSwapWindowSurface: oglSwapBuffer failed
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2578): eglSwapBuffers: EGL error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening? any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is that I was generating textures repeatedly without ever deleting them. Simply adding one line before generation is enough to prevent a memory leak (it seems there is no need to check that a texture has already been generated):

```
 gl.glDeleteTextures(1, texturesFPS, 1);
 gl.glGenTextures(1, texturesFPS, 1);
```

Simple as that :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be "gl.glGenTextures(1, texturesFPS, 0);" in the second line?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're creating a new texture each time you call `loadFPSTexture()`, and never release it. After some time this will cause you to run out of memory, which could explain the `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` in your logs.

It would be better to create your `bitmap`, `canvas` and `texturesFPS` variables just once, and reuse them in the `loadFPSTexture`() function. In that case, you should probably use `GLUtils.texSubImage2D()` instead of `GLUtils.texImage2D()`, to upload new bitmap data to the existing texture.

Comment: Will try that and let you know how it goes. I thought that bitmap.recycle would take care of releasing the used memory. I guess the texture gets made and then because it's outside of normal GC (due to buffer) it doesn't really clear the texture?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have comment access yet (frequent other 'help' sites, just getting up on SO), but wanted to echo (and upvoted) svdree's note, and add more details -- because other people starting with GLES will certainly hit similar issues.

Your bitmap, canvas, and texture (and paint!) should be created once, wherever you set up your gles resources to begin with.  They should be deleted when you clean up resources for the app.  Unless you are resizing the bitmap/texture, recreating is thrashing memory (cpu and gpu) unnecessarily.

The initial creation of the texture, you'd use the GLUtils.texImage2D function to prepare the texture (can just upload the bitmap as-is, don't care about the data).  That ensures the texture is allocated by the driver, proper width/height buffer ready for later updates.

Rendering the fps might then look more like:

```
s_bitmap.eraseColor(Color.BLACK);
s_canvas.drawText("FPS "+reportedFramerate, 10, 35, s_textPaint);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, s_texturesFPS[0]);
GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, s_bitmap);
```

... and that's it.  An order of magnitude faster, and obviously much cleaner. :-)

You can make it even faster beyond that, for example only erase/fill the bitmap rectangle where the fps is being drawn, and then use gl.glTexSubImage2D directly to upload only those rows the text is rendered to (saving you clearing, and uploading, say 220 extra rows of data that isn't changing...).

Hope that helps!